# Image above title (Github README.rst)

Tags: github, restructuredtext

I seek to put a centered image before the document title, but latter keeps forcing itself to top; if I insert a `|` between, then `====`, `----`, and all subsequent section headers are much smaller. No such problem in  Markdown.

Can an image precede a document's title in `.rst`?

---

My approach:

```html
.. raw:: html

    <p align="center"><img src=""></p>

Title
=====
```

Answer (score 1):

Titles and subtitles should be over- and underlined.

Also [`raw` is not recommended](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through). The [`image`](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#image) directive is preferred.  It has an `:align: center` option, or can be styled with a custom CSS `:class:` option.

The following works for me, where the rendered HTML is `<h1>Title</h1>` as desired and the image above the title.

```
.. image:: relative-path-to/image.*
    :align: center

=====
Title
=====
```

Comment: [Doesn't work](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/dev_tg/tree/OverLordGoldDragon-patch-1) (same with path to local file), vs [markdown](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/dev_tg/tree/README-1)

Comment: Do you mean in your `README.rst`? The filename `README.rst` is due to GitHub's UI, not Sphinx or reStructuredText. Otherwise I see the image above the title as you desire.

Comment: The image is above the title, but neither is it centered, nor is title of right fontsize.

Comment: In case our browsers somehow show different: [.rst](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgTIo.png) vs [.md](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mcrW.png) (latter is desired). I tried in Firefox and Edge.

Comment: Oh, I see. GitHub supports .md, but has [suboptimal support for reST/docutils/Sphinx](https://docs.github.com/en?query=restructuredtext). I assumed you wanted the rendering done by Sphinx, not GitHub. Feature request!